# LINQ Sorting, Titles grouped by Author

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

So currently, I have a program that sorts a list of books & authors.  Right now, it is outputting by authors grouped by title, meaning it prints the author's name & all the books he/she wrote.  Well I'm trying to reverse that & have it output by book, & then all the authors that wrote that book.  Much help will greatly be appreciated.

```
// get authors and titles of each book
        // they co-authored; group by author
        var titlesByAuthor =
            from author in dbcontext.Authors
            orderby author.LastName, author.FirstName
            select new
            {
                Name = author.FirstName + " " + author.LastName,
                Titles =
                from book in author.Titles
                orderby book.Title1
                select book.Title1
            };

        outputTextBox.AppendText("\r\n\r\nTitles grouped by author:");

        // display titles written by each author, grouped by author
        foreach (var author in titlesByAuthor)
        {
            //display author's name
            outputTextBox.AppendText("\r\n\t" + author.Name + ":");
            // display titles written by that author
            foreach (var title in author.Titles)
            {
                outputTextBox.AppendText("\r\n\t\t" + title);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @DanielMann reversing the foreach's, but to no avail.  also just messing around/trial & error.  this is the last part & i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Please use linq group by operator to group by books. Here is a sample:

```
public void Linq40() 
{ 
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 

    var numberGroups = 
        from n in numbers 
        group n by n % 5 into g 
        select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g }; 

    foreach (var g in numberGroups) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers with a remainder of {0} when divided by 5:", g.Remainder); 
        foreach (var n in g.Numbers) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(n); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I don't think that helps me here?  Basically I need to reverse what i'm doing, but I'm kind of stuck in how to print out book first & then the authors of that book after it.  Instead of what I'm doing now, which is printing the Author first, then the books after them.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you what you need:

```
var booksByAuthor =
    from book in dbcontext.Books
    orderby book.Title1
    select new
    {
        Authors = 
            from a in book.Authors
            orderby a.LastName, a.FirstName
            select a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName
        Titles = book.Title1
    };
```

You should be able to figure out the other part by yourself.

**Update**

```
foreach (var book in booksByAuthor)
{
    //display book's title
    outputTextBox.AppendText("\r\n\t" + book.Title1 + ":");

    // display authors of that book
    foreach (var author in book.Authors)
    {
        outputTextBox.AppendText("\r\n\t\t" + author);
    }
}
```